# How to create a form and be able to input the data from the form into a text file and be able to output a contents of a text file in HTML

Tags: html

I have successfully hosted an .onion website but I don't have much experience in HTML codes. I need someone to tell me how to create a form + be able to input the submitted stuff inside the form (raw) into a text file + output the contents of a text file. Thanks :) Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow, please read this and edit your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding regarding your requirement, try below stuffs.

In view page(page for input form) use the below `HTML` code.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input name="field1" type="text" />
            <input name="field2" type="text" />
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
        <button><a href='file_data.php'>Get file data</a></button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below the above `HTML` code use the `PHP` code below for processing submitted form inputs and to add the submitted form data to a text file(`data.txt`). The text file will be automatically created if it's not existing.

**NB**: You can also use a `PHP` file for this, for eg: `form.php`. In that case use `<form action="form.php" method="POST">` in the above `HTML` code.

Create a file `file_data.php` and use below code.

```
$myFile = "data.txt";
$lines = file($myFile);//file in to an array

foreach($lines as $line) 
{
    echo $line.'<br>';
}
```

Now, if you click on **Get file data** button in view page, data added to the text file will be printed.

Comment: Share ur codes. Thus only we can track regarding the error response.

Comment: Are u using PHP for backend?